# Get value from gridview to formview in insert mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formview

Is there a way to get the value from gridview and then paste it in a textbox in formview? I'm trying to get the selected datakeys like ID, firstname, lastname and insert it on a textbox in formview (i've set the defaultmode to 'insert'). I've tried it with a textbox by using the SelectedIndexMethod but how can I do it in formview textbox while in 'insert' mode?

Help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value` will give you what you are looking for.

In your `formView`, it will be like:

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%#GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

**Edit:**

```
 <asp:TextBox Text='<%#GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text %>'></asp:TextBox>
 // Cells[0] column index of your Gridview
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it right away! How can I past it again to the formview textbox?? is it like 'code'string id = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString(); 
FormView1.FindControl("idTextBox").Text = id;'code'

Comment: <asp:TextBox Text='<%#GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value %>'></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Thanks! It worked!! Btw if I may ask how can I call the other datakeys? So far I can only get the primary key (ID). What if I want to get the 'firstname' or 'lastname'?

Comment: I have edit my answer, check the edit part, you have to give cell index of your First Name column.

Comment: @Loupi; I have not used the code that I have provided, but I guess it should work and it works :) lol........

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Lol no wonder it still display the ID only :0 Still trying other alternatives at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

To get values from different cells you can try this:

```
string fn = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text; //assuming first column is FirstName
string ln = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text
```

Note that I assume Select Command Button is clicked i.e. SelectedRow is not null.